# Numpy array to image is blurry

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I'm trying to save a numpy array as a png but the output is always blurry or the size of the image is very small. I've tried looking around SO and various other sources but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

(1) Using the following technique I get an image of the appropriate size (800x600px) but the matrix is blurry:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(matrix)
plt.savefig(filename)
```

(2) Using another technique, the image is very small (60x60px) but the matrix is not blurry:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.image.imsave('name.png', array)
```

(3) After running my python program to produce a numpy array A, if I then run the command

```
matshow(A)
```

and then I hit the save icon to save the image, the result is an image of a larger size (800x600px) and the matrix is not blurry.

Using technique (3) wouldn't be an issue, but the thing is I have a lot of numpy arrays that I need to save as images, so it would be very time consuming to use technique (3) for each array.

Note: I can't post the images because I don't have enough reputation, so here is a link to them instead: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mohtpm97xyy8ahi/AACgIpY5ECBDIbcnNRS9kd8La?dl=0

If anyone has had success producing clearer images of a larger size, like those in technique 3, any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which are the dimensions of the array that you are trying to save? the resulting image will have the same size. The image in the `imshow` does also look blurry? Or the blur effect is just after saving it?

Comment: the array is 60 by 60. The blur only occurs after saving.

Comment: Have you tried passing `interpolation='nearest'` to `imshow`?

Comment: Try with different values of `interpolation=` in the `imshow` and different values of `dpi=` in the `savefig`.

Comment: @xnx and @iluengo - using `interpolation = 'nearest'` worked. thank you.

Comment: any example of input matrix variable would be useful.